# Can no longer sign in to @me.com or @icloud.com email address

Tags: icloud, email, apple-id

A few days ago I started noticing notifications from my email clients that there was an authentication error for my email address ending in @me.com. I tried re-entering my password several times, I changed my password, tried the @icloud.com version of the email address but unfortunately, nothing worked. I can however, still sign in to webmail at iCloud.com, and to other Apple services using these credentials, just not email.

Does anyone know what can cause this? I have quite a few internet accounts that depend on this email address.

Kind regards,
Roemer Bakker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably hit by the 'App Specific Password' feature. Apple recently changed their policy for 'third-party' Apps and Clients to require a password differing from your main AppleID password.

The following Apple Support link: [Using App-specific passwords](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204397) is a good place to start.

Comment: You were right! Quite un-Apple like to send no notification of this whatsoever... I was kind of worried that they finally discontinued @me.com email addresses ha! Thank you for your help.